# Solution for this small programm (Wrong output)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numberofnames;
    cin >> numberofnames;
    string* arr = new string[numberofnames];

    // Created an array to get all the names
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofnames; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    
    // Created a function to get and output second letter of each name
    for (int q = 0; q < numberofnames; q++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < arr[q].length(); w++) {
            // Output first letter of the first name
            if (w == 0) {
                char firstletterofirstname = arr[q][w];
                cout << firstletterofirstname;
            }
            // Output first letter of the last name
            if (arr[q][w] == ' ') {
                char firstletterofsecondname = arr[q][w];
                cout << firstletterofsecondname << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**I'm trying to solve a problem and can't find the solution**

Task:
Given a list of first and last names, take the first letter from each name to create initials and output them as a space-separated string.

Input Format:
The first input denotes the number of names in the list (N). The next N lines contain the list elements as strings.

Output Format:
A string containing the initials of each name in the original list, separated by spaces.

Sample Input:

```
3
Nick Dunburry
Tommy Newborne
David James
```

Sample Output:

```
ND TN DJ
```

I would be very glad if someone would help me solve this problem with explanations

Comment: Instead of `string* arr = new string[numberofnames];` use `std::vector<std::string> arr(numberofnames);`. And instead of `arr[q]` use `arr.at(q)`. And instead of `arr[q][w]` use `arr.at(q).at(w)`. If you go out of bounds you will have an exception. If you don't get an exception, then at least you know that you're not going out of bounds.

Comment: Besides that, please learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. Use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring all variables and their values

Comment: As a hint, please explain the code for the case `if (arr[q][w] == ' ')` to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or a friend. Explain it in *great* detail. For example, what is `arr[q][w]`? What will you assign to `firstletterofsecondname`? What will you print?

Comment: You have not described, what issue do you have. `cin >> arr[i];` does read multi-word lines.

Comment: Oh and `if (arr[q][w] == ' ')` will never be true actually. The `>>` operator reads *space delimited* string, and leaves out the space. You will never have a space in your input.

Comment: First things first: Turn that C program with a bit of syntactic sugar sprinkled over it into a proper C++ program: Do **not** use pointers unless you absolutely have to. Do **not** use "naked" `new`. (`vector<string> arr` would do quite nice here.) Use range-for instead of C `for`'s. The next thing to do would be to check `cin` for success after trying to read `int` from it. (Kind of like "never use `scanf()` without checking the return value".)

Comment: @OP FYI -- You don't need `std::string` arrays, usage of `new[]`, or any check for spaces.  Usage of `std::getline`, and then `std::istringstream` [is all you need](https://godbolt.org/z/Gxe5xKxq5).  I won't spend the time explaining -- if you don't know what these do, I suggest getting good C++ books and [proper websites](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to get information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a reminder to try not to `using namespace std;` because of reasons that can be found [here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). You can use add `std::` to different parts of the code to maintain that you are using that namespace.

If you want to know what problems are in **your** code, then look below the 2 cases. However, if you want a new approach, keep reading here.

Now, look, you can actually solve this problem with a lot easier code and even less memory, though it depends on how you need to output your initials. If you can output while inputting, the code can be a lot shorter and you don't even need an array. However, if you need to output everything at once after all inputs, then you need an answer array, but this can still be easily implemented. You see, all you need is the first letters of a set of 2 strings. This means you could just input those two and compute it before you input the next. More explanation in the code below:

Case 1:

```
//If you need to output after all inputs:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    int numberofnames; // the number of names
    std::vector <std::string> answers; // our answer array
    std::cin >> numberofnames;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofnames; ++i) {
        std::string firstName, lastName;
        std::cin >> firstName >> lastName;
        answers.push_back((std::string) ("" + firstName[0] + lastName[0]))
        //the + operator concatenates the characters, and then we make sure to convert it to a string and add it to the answer
    }
    for (std::string x : answers) { std::cout << x << ' '; }
    //for every string that is an answer, output it with space separators
    return 0;
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
//If you can output and input at the same time:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    int numberofnames; // the number of names
    std::cin >> numberofnames;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofnames; ++i) {
        std::string firstName, lastName;
        std::cin >> firstName >> lastName;
        std::cout << firstName[0] << lastName[0] << ' '; //output it directly after every set of input
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, if you want to know specifically what is wrong with your own code, you r entire second loop has some problems:

0. *Just a note: your second loop is not a function. In C++ there are entirely different entities named functions. While some may understand that you just mean you created a loop process, watch out for confusion.*
1. **Input Understanding issue**: You have to realize that when you use  `std::cin` to input a string, C++ puts all characters into the string until it hits a space or a carriage return in the console or stream. It doesn't guarantee that you input a whole line. Refer to functions like `getline` for more information on how to input 1 whole line into 1 string in one go. Therefore, when you have your if statement checking for the space, it will never happen.
2. **Written Code Issue with Output**: Even within that if statement, there are some problems. First, in the if itself, you check if it is a space. If it is, you save that character, which is a space, and then you output it, meaning you outputted 1 space character. To fix this, just add 1 to the `w` and you will get the first character **after** the space.

**Your New Code with Corrections based on Your Old Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    int numberofnames;
    std::cin >> numberofnames;
    std::string* arr = new std::string[numberofnames];
    std::string trashNewLine;// leftover trash storage
    std::getline(std::cin, trashNewLine); // take away the leftover newline character from our previous cin for the number of names
    // Created an array to get all the names
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofnames; i++) {
        std::getline(std::cin, arr[i]);
        //get the entire line of the name, stopping only at the carriage return, meaning you have the space inside the string arr[i]
    }
    for (int q = 0; q < numberofnames; q++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < arr[q].length(); w++) {
            // You can output the characters directly from the string array. You don't need an extra character just to store it. The character takes up memory anyway.
            // Output first letter of the first name
            if (w == 0) { std::cout << arr[q][w]; }
            // Output first letter of the last name
            if (arr[q][w] == ' ') { std::cout << arr[q][w + 1] << ' '; }
            //Just add 1 to w, meaning if arr[q][w] is the space, then the one right after is the first character of the last name
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just got so depressed because of so many informations and mistakes, ill analyse your code. Thank you again

Comment: @frogProg You are very welcome. This genuinely isn't too bad a question in my eyes. Although it lacks details and other conventional question-asking aspects the code has some problems that can be very problematic to more experienced users. I hope you get this question right.